# N-by-2 grid, and if the last row has only a single column, center it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, centering, grid-layout

I want to have an N-by-2 grid like this, in which some elements (columns) might be set to `display:none` based on run-time factors, making the number of rows and columns unknown in advance at the design time. So it could look like this:

```
1 2
3 4
 5
```

or

```
1 2
4 5 (3 is missing)
```

or

```
1 3 (2, 5 is missing)
 4  (4 is the last column)
```

I want the last element to be always centered.

I make each `div` `.col-xs-6` to make the grid N-by-2.

What can I do to make the last column to always be in center? Last column,  which is unknown in advance at the design time, so I can't do anything particularly to it like offset it, because I can only offset all the columns because any of them could potentially be the last column.

http://jsfiddle.net/d8xwyzza/

If this isn't something that can't be done with CSS or Bootstrap alone please let me know as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you can use `last-child` property. But you need to find the `odd last element`, because even last element no need to come in center place. So you can use it in the following way.

```
.col-xs-6
{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}
.col-xs-6:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd) { /* This will find last child with odd element */
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/d8xwyzza/2/)

Answer (score 2):

[**JSfiddle Demo - Option 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/d8xwyzza/1/)

Note this requires **not** using floats and switching to `display:inline-block`.

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:0;
}

.col-xs-6 {
    float:none;
    font-size:1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

[**JSfiddle - Option 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3kcmsko/2/)

Using standard floats and clearing the last one.

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
}

.col-xs-6 {

    border:1px solid grey;
}

.col-xs-6:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd) {
    clear:both;
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

EDIT: See Suresh's comment about the last child needing to be odd. **Updated**.

Answer (score 0):

With [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/#row-columns-gutters:%7E:text=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22row%20row%2Dcols%2D2%20row%2Dcols%2Dlg%2D5%20g%2D2%20g%2Dlg%2D3%22%3E):

```html
<div class="row row-cols-2 justify-content-center">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
  <div class="col">5</div>
</div>
```